# Logical Operator in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-5

How can I connect two queries by Logical Operator of **AND OR NOT** in laravel Eloquent

Select `title`, `author` **where (**`TITLE` LIKE %computer% or `SUBJECT` LIKE %computer% **)**

**NOT**

*(* `AUTHOR` LIKE %thomas% **or** `IMPRINT` LIKE %thomas%**)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your query is not working like that.
Assuming that your table indeed is named `book1` the query is probably like this:

```
SELECT TITLE, AUTHOR FROM book1 
 where (Title like 'computer' or Subject like 'computer')
 AND NOT (imprint like 'delhi' or series like 'abc')
```

Now if you have an eloquent model that is called Book1, you can formulate the query as:

```
Book1::where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('title', 'like', 'computer');
    $query->orWhere('subject', 'like', 'computer');
})->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('imprint', 'not like', 'delhi');
    $query->orWhere('series', 'not like', 'abc');
})->get();
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

To answer on your comment, you can connect multiple queries (and create groupings) by making use of inner functions. Everything within an inner function is written within brackets.
The above query would therefore be:

```
SELECT * FROM Book1 WHERE 
( title like 'computer' OR subject like 'computer' )
AND
( imprint not like 'delhi' OR series not like 'abc' )
```

If you would rather connect both with `OR` instead of `AND`, you can combine them via `orWhere` instead of `where` in Eloquent.

```
Book1::where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('title', 'like', 'computer');
    $query->orWhere('subject', 'like', 'computer');
})->orWhere(function ($query) {
    $query->where('imprint', 'not like', 'delhi');
    $query->orWhere('series', 'not like', 'abc');
})->get();
```

Comment: Really I got good understanding from your answer. I am greatful that. One more doubt, how can I connect two queries **by logical operator**, ie ,  **(Query1) AND/OR/NOT (Query2)**

Comment: The grouping happens in the inner function. Imagine that the inner function is within brackets. So it translates to `... where (title like computer or subject like computer)`. The next `->where` is automatically an "AND", followed by brackets because of the inner function. Then you have `...where (title like computer or subject like computer) AND (imprint not like delhi or series not like abc)`.
If you want to connect via `OR` instead of `AND` you would need to use `->orWhere`